# How do I locate CouchDB's local.ini file so I can customize its settings?

Tags: configuration, couchdb

I've installed CouchDB (to run a local npm registry) and need to locate the local.ini file so I can customize the couch settings.

How do I find the local.ini file?

Answer (score 11):

Run the following to display the chain of configuration files CouchDB uses, which should include the local.ini file:

```
couchdb -c
```

Example output:

```
/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini
/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini
```

Comment: couchdb -c No such file or directory

Comment: how to find couch.ini file

Comment: kernel-poll not supported; "K" parameter ignored

Answer (score 8):

For Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver), installing from the package repository, I found it in here:

```
/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini
```